# how to get affiliate details from JVZOO using affiliate id

Tags: javascript, php, api

I am integarting JVZOO PHP API to get product and affiliates details.
But I am not getting any API which can allow me to get affiliate details like First Name and Last Name. I just wanted to fetch the affiliates which are associated with my product.

Comment: Please post what code you've tried. Take a look at the site's [help section on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Did you found any solution, I need to fetch approved products.